# How does std::unordered_map return correct value from a bucket

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;`

Then inserting tons of elements into this but the string keys are all unique.

Is the following scenario possible and how is it handled?

```
map[x] = 5;
map[y] = 3;
```

Lets assume `x` and `y` are different strings but they produce the same hash, so 5 and 3 are placed in the same bucket.

When we try to retrieve the value with `map[x]` how does the map return the correct value 5? Hashing `x` will give the bucket with the two elements 5, 3 but I don't see how it gets the correct value without having the key itself to compare against.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you ever written a hash-table implementation before?

Comment: @WhozCraig no I haven't.

Comment: The map, of course, must store the key together with the value, not just its hash. If only because `map.begin()->first` must return the key. So once it gets into the right bucket, it does a regular search there.

Comment: In any hashtable a hash is just a way to get to the bucket. It's like a clue. Once you get there you still need to do equality comparison to retrieve the results. Infact it's possible to have a hashtable where all values have the same hash. It'll just perform horribly.

Comment: [hash table collision resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

Comment: Your closing statement is *almost* correct (subset "key" for "value"). The key leads to a collision list The list enumeration requires key-by-key comparison to resolve to the *correct* entry. Think of it as a table of linked lists. The hash function tells you which slot in the table to go to, the list contains all entries that hashed to that slot, from there a linear (or logN if the list is maintained as sorted) search ensues based on the key values.

Comment: Yeah all cleared up now, thanks. Was thinking `key` no idea why I typed value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full declaration of [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) looks like so:

```
template <
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash      = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual  = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, T>>
> class unordered_map;
```

Observe that it requires both a hash function and an equality comparer for the key type.

When searching for the element with a particular key, the container will first find the correct bucket using the hash function, then will walk the elements in that bucket, comparing the key of each element using the equality comparer.

Answer (score 1):

The bucket is just that, a bucket. unordered_map is actually a template, taking, among other things, a key and value type, and a function that checks keys for equality (defaults to `std::equal_to<KeyType>`) It uses the equality comparison to find the element in the bucket that matches the value you're searching for.

hash tables in general degenerate to linear or log time if you're completely evil and feed them keys with significant numbers of collisions, in practice they're generally close to O(1).

Comment: I think you'll find, if you think about it, that your first statement is not actually true.  The bucket is not *really* a bucket.  That's just a metaphor.